# How to repeat a method in Java

Tags: java, methods

In general, how do you repeat (or maybe recall, I'm not to clear with the jargon as of yet) a method? Like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the keys");
        String input = keyboard.next();
        if (input.equals("a")) {
            System.out.println("0");
        }
```

How would you make it so that you could rerun this method, and keep on inputting more data?
Like, when you use (batch programming language)

```
:a
(function here)
goto a
```

Comment: You're probably interested in reading up on looping constructs. (Google "java loop")

Comment: Read about control flow in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html. You will learn about loops like `while` `do-while` and `for`.

Comment: Right, thanks! I wasn't sure how to use those. Do you have any books you recommend to learn this stuff?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = "";

    while (input.equals ("q") == false) {
      System.out.println("Enter the keys");
      input = keyboard.next();
      if (input.equals("a")) {
        System.out.println("0");
      }
    }
```

This will keep looping until the user presses `q`

Comment: `while(!input.equals ("q"))` avoid accidental assignment

Comment: @WalterM - that would not compile, The left hand side need to be a variable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that? Of course it will compile `!true == false`. Try it if you like `System.out.println(!true == false);`

Comment: No, what you are implying by `accidental assignment`  i.e. `while (input.equals ("q") = false)` will not compile, so my code is simply more verbose and more readable I think for a newbie.

Comment: ok I understand what you're saying. I think it's still a double edged sword since they get used to doing stuff the wrong way they'll make a mistake somewhere down the line.